# How to add a pandas numeric column on a dataframe based on availability of category slots of other dataset, using a pythonic solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset of tickets that contains tiers and ids as follows.

```
df_tickets = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], columns=['tier']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'ticket_id'})
```

```
ticket_id   tier

0           A
1           A
2           A
3           B
4           B
5           B
6           C
```

I also have a dataset with users and their respective target tiers below.

```
df_users = pd.DataFrame([['Anna', 'A'], ['Brian', 'A'], ['Cloe', 'C'], ['Dylan', 'C']], columns=['user', 'tier'])
```

```
user        tier

Anna        A
Brian       A
Cloe        C
Dylan       C
```

My goal is to get, for each user in `df_users`, the correpondent `ticket_id` from `df_ticket`. For non available ticket tiers, the final values should be a default one such as `-1`.

```
user        tier   ticket_id

Anna        high    0
Brian       high    1
Cloe        low     6
Dylan       low    -1
```

I was able to reach the desired values but using the following iterative solution.

```
tickets_dict = {k:[] for k in df_tickets['tier'].unique()}

for tier in df_tickets['tier'].unique():
  for index, row in df_tickets[df_tickets['tier'] == tier].iterrows():
      tickets_dict[tier].append(row['ticket_id'])

for index, row in df_users.iterrows():
  df_users.loc[index, 'ticket_id'] = tickets_dict[row['tier']].pop(0) if tickets_dict[row['tier']] else -1

df_users['ticket_id'] = df_users['ticket_id'].astype(int)
```

How to reach these values employing a pythonic simpler more direct solution?

Answer (score 0):

A viable pythonic solution could start by creating dummy temporary keys for the tiers in both dataframes using the `cumcount` method.

```
df_tickets['temp_key'] = df_tickets.groupby(['tier']).cumcount()
```

```
ticket_id   tier    temp_key

0           A       0
1           A       1
2           A       2
3           B       0
4           B       1
5           B       2
6           C       0
```

```
df_users['temp_key'] = df_users.groupby(['tier']).cumcount()
```

```
user    tier    temp_key

Anna    A       0
Brian   A       1
Cloe    C       0
Dylan   C       1
```

Next you can execute a left join merge of the `df_tickets` dataframe into the `df_users`, using both the the `tier` and the temporary `temp_key` columns as join keys. Here we also drop the temporary key, which has served its purpose.

```
df_users_tickets = df_users.merge(df_tickets, how='left', on=['tier', 'temp_key']).drop(columns=['temp_key'])
```

```
user    tier    ticket_id

Anna    A       0.0
Brian   A       1.0
Cloe    C       6.0
Dylan   C       NaN
```

Finally, to arrive at the desired values, we just get rid of the `NaN` values with the desired default value, and set the data type for the column.

```
df_users_tickets['ticket_id'] = df_users_tickets['ticket_id'].fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

With all previous steps together we arrive at the final solution.

```
df_tickets['temp_key'] = df_tickets.groupby(['tier']).cumcount()
df_users['temp_key'] = df_users.groupby(['tier']).cumcount()
df_users_tickets = df_users.merge(df_tickets, how='left', on=['tier', 'temp_key']).drop(columns=['temp_key'])
df_users_tickets['ticket_id'] = df_users_tickets['ticket_id'].fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

```
user    tier    ticket_id

Anna    A       0
Brian   A       1
Cloe    C       6
Dylan   C       -1
```